# CupertinoDatePicker in ModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, exception, datepicker

Can't manage to put the CupertinoDatePicker into the bottom modal in Flutter.

Getting the following: `RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.`

```
...

          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            CupertinoDatePicker(
                              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                              initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                              onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime) {
                                // tbd
                              },
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("save"))
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
                icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar, size:30, color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            )
...
```

I too new to Flutter to understand how I work around this problem :

```
This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.

...

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CupertinoDatePicker CupertinoDatePicker
```

Comment: for those who have this problem when using a `Stepper` widget, make sure you hot restart when trying out the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `CupertinoDatePicker` widget gets an infinite size during rendering. To solve that you could wrap the widget with a `Container` widget, or a `SizedBox` widget, and giving it a `height`:

```
...

          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 300, // Just as an example
                              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime)   {
                                // tbd
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("save"))
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
                icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar, size:30, color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            )
...
```

An alternative is to wrap the `CupertinoDatePicker` with an `Expanded` widget. An `Expanded` widget makes its child fill the available space (instead of trying to fill an infinite height).

```
...

          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime)   {
                                // tbd
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("save"))
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
                icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar, size:30, color: Colors.orange),
              ),
            )
...
```